# Parent retrieve variable setting in child(included) page jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, crud

Im doing  a simple `crud` in  java using `jsp` and `servlets`.
And I came acrross with this situation:

I have a `layout.jsp` what does a include to another page dynamics, in this case is `exclude.jsp`. The title of page is set inside `exclude.jsp`, Becouse of that  `layout.jsp` cannot see the value of my `title` variable.

Ask: how to do `layout.jsp` see the value of `title`.

**Obs:** I'm trying hard, not put the variable inside a `servlet`. I know, if I put the value in  a `servlet` the  `layout .jsp` can see.

> layout.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"       prefix="c"   %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"       prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"       prefix="x"   %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"       prefix="sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"  %>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><c:out value="${title}" /></title>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<c:import url="menu.jsp" />
<div class="container">
    <c:import url = "${page}" />
</div>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> exclude.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"       prefix="c"   %>
<c:set var="title" scope="request" value="Excluir página"/>
<h1><c:out value="${title}" /></h1>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642010/how-to-pass-data-back-from-included-jsp-to-parent-page?rq=1

Comment: They use a `servlet` to accomplishment.

Answer (score 0):

I put the same question in http://pt.stackoverflow.com and fortunately someone already answer.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186033/passar-vari%C3%A1vel-da-pagina-filha-para-a-pa%C7%B5ina-pai-em-jsp/186064#186064

Comment: As a lusophone, I can easily read, but I think that it should be interesting if you translate it here so that this answer can reach a greater public withou Moisés coming from software translators